# Simple project using gpio

Tags: gpio

I want to do a simple project for work. I want to take 3 inputs in. If I don't receive these 3 inputs within a certain time I want to produce a reject screen on a monitor and if I do get the three signals then I get a pass maybe with a green background. Anyone seen anything like this before. I am not worried abouts the inputs as I can drop them to 3.3v it's more the software side of it.
Thanks

Comment: From  a software viewpoint this is simple.  Perhaps look at the free magazine https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/

Comment: I use raspberry PI for production test in a similar manner, but we have invested much time and design into an internal framework to make these tests repeatable and controlled for production environment. It is a doable problem, and raspberry pi is a good platform, but you will need to invest design resources beyond what can be answered in a single stack exchange question

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach for a trivial test application using bash that uses the shell function `dialog` to present a result screen

```
#!/bin/bash
# Loops on inputs and displays a dialog if pass condition 
# If loop terminates fail condition is displayed
# No error checking or time-out, quit with ctrl-c

# define pins here
NPINS="3"
PINS="2 3 4"
#timeout in seconds
TIMEOUT="10"

while [ $TIMEOUT -gt 0 ];
do
   RES=$NPINS
   for pin in $PINS; do
     # if pin is on, subtract
     let "RES -= `gpio read $pin`"
   done

   if [[ $RES="0" ]]; then
      dialog --title "Test Result" --msgbox 'Test Pass!' 6 20
      clear
      exit 0
   fi
   sleep 1
   let TIMEOUT=TIMEOUT-1

done

dialog --title "Test Result" --msgbox 'Test Fail!' 6 20
clear
exit 1
```

*script tested, but not with gpio inputs*

Comment: Hi guys how fast signals can the pi handle. Is 40ms too fast for the pi. Thanks for the answers so far